# Not able to parse correct value from retrofit JSON response in Android studio

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I'm trying to fetch the `orderid` from my MySQL database through retrofit API post call. The actual data is coming in JSON format through `arrOrderStatus.toString()`, but I'm unable to extract exact value using `arrOrderStatus.get(i).getOrderid()`. The app is crashing after printing step 3 (as shown in pic below), and before printing step 4.

Where am I doing the silly mistake?

Function in main activity to call retofit API:

```
private void fetchingOrderStatusData(String mobilenumber) {
       Call<List<response_model_order_status>> call = apicontroller
               .getInstance()
               .getApi()
               .getOrderStatus(mobilenumber);

       call.enqueue(new Callback<List<response_model_order_status>>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<List<response_model_order_status>> call, Response<List<response_model_order_status>> response) {
               Log.d("AAAAAAAA", "Service is running..." + mobilenumber + "--1--");
               List<response_model_order_status> arrOrderStatus = response.body();
               Log.d("AAAAAAAA", "Service is running..." + mobilenumber + arrOrderStatus.toString() + "--2--");
               for (int i = 0; i < arrOrderStatus.size(); i++) {
                   Log.d("AAAAAAAA", "Service is running..." + mobilenumber + "--3--");
                   Log.d("AAAAAAAA", "Service is running..." + arrOrderStatus.get(i).getOrderid() + "--4--");
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<List<response_model_order_status>> call, Throwable t) {
               Log.d("AAAAAAAA", "Service is running..." + mobilenumber + "--5--");
           }
       });
    }
```

apiset.java:

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("get_order_status.php")
    Call<List<response_model_order_status>> getOrderStatus(
            @Field("mobilenumber") String mobilenumber
    );
```

get_order_status.php code:

```php
<?php

require 'connection.php';

$mobilenumber=trim($_POST['mobilenumber']);
        
$qry="select X.orderid from orderlist X where X.mobilenumber='$mobilenumber' and X.ordertime >= CURDATE() order by X.ordertime DESC";

$raw=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
 
while ($res=mysqli_fetch_array($raw))
{
    $data[]=$res;
}

print json_encode($data);

mysqli_commit($con);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

In MySQL database, both `mobilenumber` and `orderid` columns are `varchar(20)` in table `orderlist`.

Response model:

```
public class response_model_order_status {
    String orderid;

    public response_model_order_status() {
    }

    public response_model_order_status(String orderid) {
        this.orderid = orderid;
    }

    public String getOrderid() {
        return orderid;
    }

    public void setOrderid(String orderid) {
        this.orderid = orderid;
    }
}
```

Log.d output and error message:

[image]

I tried putting different syntax codes to parse `arrOrderStatus.get(i).getOrderid()`, but unable to do so.

Comment: According to the image of your error, you are getting `ClassCastException`. Do you know what that is? Are you doing an explicit cast in your code? I did not see any explicit cast in the code in your question. By the way, it is recommended **not** to post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) of your error.

Comment: I really fail to understand from where this ClassCastException is happening. If I remove this function fetchingOrderStatusData() or even if I remove that inside FOR loop from my MainActivity, then app is running perfectly fine with no crashes. That means some issues with the code: arrOrderStatus.get(i).getOrderid(). Why it's not able to extract correct info whereas we can get desired values through arrOrderStatus.toString().

Comment: `com.project.localshop` - is that your package? If it is then according to the stack trace, you should look at line 235 in file `SourceFile`.

Comment: At line 235, nothing is there, just a comment. As I told before, If I remove this function fetchingOrderStatusData() or even if I remove that inside FOR loop from my MainActivity, then app is running perfectly fine with no crashes. That means some issues with the code: arrOrderStatus.get(i).getOrderid() which is triggering this ClassCastException error.

Answer (score 0):

I've used R8 for obfuscation, and missed to mention `@Keep` in Response Model because of which the functions like `getOrderid()` too got obfuscated. After I added `@Keep` at the beginning of Response Model, then the code worked fine.

```
@Keep
public class response_model_order_status {
    String orderid;

    public response_model_order_status() {
    }

    public response_model_order_status(String orderid) {
        this.orderid = orderid;
    }

    public String getOrderid() {
        return orderid;
    }

    public void setOrderid(String orderid) {
        this.orderid = orderid;
    }
}
```